# ansibleでターゲットサーバにnginxを入れようとするとエラーが起こる。

Tags: ansible, amazon-linux

ansibleで複数のミルドウェアをインストールして、使えるようにする設定を自動化するため
まずは、インストールの記述からと実験しているのですがうまくいきません。
`apt-get update` するようにエラーで促されているのですが、OSの相性的に違うのではと見ています。
エラー解る方解消方法や、ansibleでのＭＷインストールのリファレンス教えていただけますと幸いです。

### 検証環境の説明

コントロールノード：amazon linux2
ターゲットノード：amazon linux2

### 実行したyamlコード

```
- name: nginxの起動ユーザーの追加
  user:
    name: nginx

- name: apt update
  apt:
    update_cache: yes

- name: nginxのインストール
  apt:
    name: nginx
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes
    cache_valid_time: 3600

- name: nginxのサービススタート
  service:
    name: nginx
    enabled: yes

- name: nginx設定ファイルの設置
  template:
    src: nginx.conf.j2
    dest: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

- name: nginx本体の設定ファイルを変更
  template:
    src: nginx.conf.j2
    dest: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  notify:
    - restart nginx
```

### 発生しているエラー文

```
PLAY [client_node] *************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host Client01 is using the discovered Python
interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python
interpreter could change this. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/referen
ce_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
ok: [Client01]
TASK [hands-on : nginxの起動ユーザーの追加] ************************************                                                                                                                                                             **********
changed: [Client01]

TASK [hands-on : nginxのインストール] ******************************************                                                                                                                                                             *******
[WARNING]: Updating cache and auto-installing missing dependency: python-apt
fatal: [Client01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "apt-get update", "msg":                                                                                                                                                              "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
Client01                   : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1    s                                                                                                                                                             kipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Linux は CentOS ベースなので、パッケージ管理のコマンドは `apt` ではなく `yum` もしくは `dnf` を使用するはずです。(`apt` は 主に Debian/Ubuntu 向けのパッケージ管理コマンドです)